# Python for x in list basic question

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which will load a whole lot of images and map them to appropriate names in PyGame. I'm not all that great with python and this really has me stuck. My current code is this:

```
tile1 = pygame.image.load("/one.bmp")
tile2 = pygame.image.load("/two.bmp")
tile3 = pygame.image.load("/three.bmp")
```

and it keeps going on for about 20 tiles. The thing is I just found out that I need a lot more and was wondering how I could do this using a *for x in y* loop. My basic idea was:

```
tile = ['/one.bmp', '/two.bmp', '/three.bmp']
tilelist = [1,2,3]
for tile in tile:
    tilelist[x] = pygame.image.load(tile)
```

or something like that but I'm not quite there. I was also wondering if it could be done using dictionaries.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: I dumped the `optimization` and `pygame` tags since they really don't have much to do with the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to the rescue.

```
tiles = ['/one.bmp', '/two.bmp', '/three.bmp']
tilelist = [pygame.img.load(tile) for tile in tiles]
```

---

As [@isakkarlsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197497/isakkarlsson) commented,

> ...or easier(?) `tilelist = map(pygame.img.load, tiles)`

Comment: You need some brackets around that list comprehension. And it should probably be `pygame.img.load(tile)`

Comment: @Rafe thanks, it's been a _long_ time since I've written any considerable amount of python.

Comment: Yes Thankyou guys. With the brackets around the list it works great :)

Comment: ..or easier(?) `tilelist = map(pygame.img.load, tiles)`

Answer (score 1):

To load the data

```
tile = ['/one.bmp', '/two.bmp', '/three.bmp']
imageMap = {}
for t in tile:
    imageMap[t] = pygame.img.load(t)
```

Then you have all the data in a dictionary and can loop through the file names using imageMap.keys() or the index directly into the dictionary to get a particular image.